# AWS SimpleDB Ruby v1 SDK delete method not working

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm trying to delete a bunch of records in an AWS SimpleDB domain using the `delete` method of the `Item` class with the AWS Ruby SDK (v1) e.g.

```
expected_total = # fetched using a count(*) query
actually_deleted = 0

query = "select * from MyDomain where Attr = '#{attr_value}'"
token = nil
begin 
   if token == nil then
      resp = sdb.select(select_expression: query)
   else
      resp = sdb.select(
         select_expression: query,
         next_token: token)
   end
   token = resp[:next_token]
   resp[:items].each do |item|
      item.delete({})
      actually_deleted += 1
      print "\rDeleted #{actually_deleted} records..." if actually_deleted % 250 == 0
   end
end while token != nil && token != ''

puts "\nComplete. Expected: #{expected_total} Actual: {actually_deleted}"
```

When it done, it reports that the expected number of records have been deleted, but they haven't. They're all still there in SimpleDB. I initially thought it might be a replica issue, that I was checking too soon. But it doesn't matter how many times I run the script, it never deletes the records.

[Here's the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/SimpleDB/Item.html#delete-instance_method) for the delete method I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to delete the records that I wanted to in the end, but I had to use the v2 SDK instead. I did something like this:

```
item_batch = []
token = nil
begin 
   if token == nil then
      resp = sdb.select(select_expression: query)
   else
      resp = sdb.select(
         select_expression: query,
         next_token: token)
   end
   token = resp[:next_token]
   resp[:items].each do |item|
      item_batch << { name: item[:name] }
      if item_batch.size == 25 then
         sdb.batch_delete_attributes({domain_name: domain_name, items: item_batch })
         item_batch = []
         actually_deleted += 25
      end
      print "\rDeleted #{actually_deleted} records..." if actually_deleted % 250 == 0
   end
end while token != nil && token != ''

if not item_batch.empty? then
   sdb.batch_delete_attributes({domain_name: domain_name, items: item_batch })
   actually_deleted += item_batch.size
end
```

Also, the client needs to initialized like `Aws::SimpleDB::Client.new` instead of `AWS::SimpleDB::Client.new`.

This might help others, although you might be stuck with the v1 SDK. I'm not accepting this answer, because it doesn't solve the problem in my question.